# Gradle exec task always runs, even with inputs == outputs

Tags: gradle

I have a simple gradle task that creates a directory

```
task foo(type: Exec) {
    inputs.dir 'foo'
    outputs.dir 'foo'

    commandLine 'mkdir', 'foo'
}
```

The problem is every time I run the task `foo` it always runs.   I would expect it to run the first time, then, realizing that the directory exists, would not run again.  What am I missing?

Also, how would this work the first time around when the `foo` directory doesn't exist?

Comment: It just a guess, but whenever you run the tasks `${buildDir}/venv` changes somehow (touch?), hence input changes and the tasks scheduled to be run. What about not keeping the `venv` under `buildDir`?

Comment: This happens if I run the task back to back so nothing should be changing in the venv

Comment: Maybe not to the content exactly, but metadata.

Comment: I changed it to a completely different dir and get the same results

Comment: Please run with `-i` to verify what  triggers the task.

Answer (score 2):

The descripion of the [`TaskInputs.dir()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs.html#dir-java.lang.Object-) method says:

> All files found under the given directory are treated as input files for this task.

So I guess whether the directory exists or not is simply not checked, but only whether files inside the directory change.

However, there is a simply workaround. Simply use a `onlyIf` closure on the task to specify when to skip it:

```
task foo(type: Exec) {
    onlyIf { file('foo').exists() }

    commandLine 'mkdir', 'foo'
}
```

I only used an `Exec` task in my example to keep it as close to your question as possible, but please note that Gradle does provide a method [`mkdir()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#mkdir-java.lang.Object-) which should be preferred over calling a command line tool. Keep in mind to execute it inside a `doFirst` or `doLast` closure, since it will be called during *configuration phase* otherwise.

Also please note that Gradle will create all necessary directories (for `Copy` tasks etc.) on its own, so it is only required to create directories manually in very rare cases..

Comment: My original question was revised to simplify what it was doing.  The true question is that I want to create a Python venv, and my task is trying to re-created the venv every time, even if I run the gradle task back to back.

Answer (score -2):

Here is one simple solution.
Use groovy script in task to create folder.

```
task foo {
    def folder = new File("foo")

    // If it doesn’t exist, create a directory.
    if( !folder.exists() ) {
        folder.mkdirs()
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not even execute during *execution phase*, but during *configuration phase*, so the task is completely pointless.

Comment: @LukasKörfer I don't know why you are saying its pointless. Question is not about configuration phase or execution phase.

Comment: Your code inside the task closure will be executed regardless of the task being executed. Post your snippet inside a `build.gradle` file and just invoke `gradle` without any tasks specified and the folder will be created. But the task itself won't do anything, therefore I called it pointless.